# Importing Action Bar Sherlock into Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I am using the new Android Studio and am having some problems importing the ABS 4.0 library. I have created a new project just as you would in Eclipse but in order to update it in Eclipse you have to do the "Add Compatibility Library..." option. Do I have to do this in Android studio? Where would it be located?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio/16588104#16588104. check this might help

Comment: Thanks I think I got it to work following one of the examples on that link

Comment: See also http://showlabor.blogspot.com/2013/05/actionbarsherlock-in-android-studio-01.html

Answer (score 0):

If you look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883237) you'll see how to add a library to the IDE.  Unfortunately I haven't worked out yet how to get it to deploy with Gradle.